# How to increase industrial demand in Sim City 4?

Tags: simcity-4

What I want to know is how to increase industrial demand in my city, I also want to know how to get more commercial demand, and jobs in general. Thank you in advance for you answers!

Comment: Dirty Industry will go just about anywhere. Decrease the taxes and it should boom!  This will also attract low income families, and in turn, more crime though.

Comment: thats odd, because I do that, and the demand still seems to be low

Comment: Is the land value too high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the Sim City 4 Wiki  http://strategywiki.org/wiki/SimCity_4/Zoning_and_Demand#Industrial:

"As for actual industry, the demand cap is raised by the freight leaving your city, therefore the industrial demand cap should be self-sustaining if you have any neighbor connections. Note that due to a bug, seaports do not count towards the industrial demand cap. There are some reward buildings which raise the demand cap as well.

To make only high-tech industry, which doesn't pollute and can get you new buildings if you have enough, go to The Monthly Budget menu and raise the taxes for Manufacturing and Dirty Industry to 20.0, which is the highest it will go. The demand for them will get really low and now if you make industry in a high desirability zone it will develop as High-Tech Industry. If it doesn't, to help lower taxes for High-Tech a little or build parks and commercial all around it, but note that you will need to provide a well educated population as well as a supply of water."